# When did Madelyne Pryor replace Jean Grey?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-97, x-men-the-animated-series

In *X-Men '97* (season 1, episode 3, "Fire Made Flesh"), it was revealed that

> a clone of Jean Grey, Madelyne Pryor (also known as the Goblin Queen), took Jean Grey's place at some point, courtesy of Mr. Sinister.

This made me wonder if Sinister's switcheroo might have happened during the events of the *X-Men '97* prequel, *X-Men: The Animated Series*.

Is there any information available to pinpoint when, in the original series, Jean Grey was replaced by Madelyne Pryor?

I'm open to insights from the comics as well, if the series leaves this detail unclear.

Comment: Screencrush had some theories https://youtu.be/a6fNN-5xbtQ?si=O-j3A9XIRni7JH6Q